# Adding CSS class to an image using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using this javascript code snippet in order to add a CSS class "aziz" to the first image in the [page](https://www.nardebangroup.com/blog/%D8%A8%DA%A9-%D9%84%DB%8C%D9%86%DA%A9/). I don't know why, but the CSS class is added after user interaction. I added this script in the head of my website. Does any body have any idea how Can I fix this?

```html
<script>
document.querySelector('.attachment-large,.size-large').classList.add('aziz')
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you wait until the dom is loaded? Perhaps the element does not exist yet.

Comment: _"I added this script in the head of my website"_ No you didn't. You have some sort of lazy load on this script: `<script data-minify="1" data-type="lazy" data-src="..."></script>`. It's only loaded on user interaction/mouse move